# How to log user input with Morgan?

Tags: javascript, express, backend, morgan

Good morning,

I am trying to log user input from user when using morgan and express. What I am specifically trying to log is noted in this image: (The user posted a request with an object that includes two key/value pairs "name" and "number")

[image: Image of logger]

How would I go about logging this? Custom tokens or is there a predefined method I could use?

Comment: Note that this is an extremely bad practice. You really don't want user input in your log files from a security or privacy standpoint. Usually when user input (especially PII like names) winds up in log files, most companies consider this a significant incident.

Comment: I understand, but this is just for practice nothing being implemented in a real application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, very simple:

```
app.use(express.json())

morgan.token("code", function getCode(req) {
  return JSON.stringify(req.body);
 });

app.use(morgan(':method :url :response-time :code'))
```

`JSON.stringify(req.body)` was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to write logs to a file:

```js
// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), { flags: 'a' })

// setup the logger
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: accessLogStream }))
```

You can find further references at the [official Morgan documentation on how to write logs to a file](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#write-logs-to-a-file)